# setup localhost on windows 8 with wamp or whatever

Tags: windows-8, localhost, wamp

I want to use localhost on windows 8. I've tried installing Wamp and it works except for i need a microsoft file named msvcr100.dll. I've downloaded it but it isn't compatible with windows 8. (or i just cant find the right one).

Any ideas how to make this work? another service provider or anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "using localhost"? Please be more specific, as it stands there is no way to answer this.

Comment: i mean i want to use localhost for testing for example php applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost is for loopback IP which is 127.0.0.1. Every computer even linux has a loopback IP. Localhost is available by default in HOSTS file of windows. Application installation wont make  difference to localhost address.If your HOST file is damaged alternately you even try your computer name or IP provided by router(192.168.0.XXX) if you want to access WAMP.

And if you want to repair HOSTS file follow this [link](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/). Only alter this file if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I downloaded easyphp and it works perfect. But youre right, I just dont know what Im doing.